# BufferedInputStream not working with random seeks in file

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedinputstream

The write procedure to my file was as follows (in the mode which I call non-clustered)

> 1. Write an object to the current position of the file. Note the position of write in another file (called the index file) so I know where have I placed the objects.
> 2. Leave some space (Randomly 1/2/3/4 KB of space) by writing zero bytes
> 3. Repeat steps 1 and 2

Now I decided to read the objects back from the file. But I wanted to use `BufferedInputStream`. However when I encapsulate a `BufferedInputStream` inside an ObjectInputStream I get errors after reading some of the objects. I am guessing this happens *after* One buffered Read (i.e. as many objects as can fit in the buffer are read once, the next time I get an error).

On the Other hand encapsulating a `FileInputStream` directly inside a `ObjectInputStream` works without any problem.

If needed, I will provide the file writing code too. Feel free to ask anything about the code below.

`public class RecordsFileReader {
    RecordsFile rFile;
    Iterator itr;
    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;`

```
// The constructor
public RecordsFileReader(RecordsFile rFile) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    this.rFile = rFile;
    fis = new FileInputStream(rFile.getFileName());


    ObjectInputStream ois2 = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(rFile.getFileName() + ".index"));



    rFile.recordsLocationList =  (ArrayList <Long>) ois2.readObject();
    itr = rFile.recordsLocationList.iterator();
   /**********************************************************/
   /*          HERE IS THE PROBLEM.                          */
   /* Doesnt work when I additionally use BufferedInputStream*/
   /**********************************************************/

    ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

   /**********************************************************/     
}

public Tuple readNext() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if(!itr.hasNext())
        return null;
    Long nextRecordPosition = itr.next();
    fis.getChannel().position(nextRecordPosition);
    //System.out.println((Tuple) ois.readObject());
    return ((Tuple) ois.readObject());
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    ois.close();
    fis.close();



}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return itr.hasNext();

}
```

}

`public class RecordsFile {`

```
boolean clustered;
private String fileName;

public RecordsFile(String fileName, boolean clustered) throws IOException {
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.clustered = clustered;
}

/*
The byte positions at which the records are located in the file.
*/
ArrayList<Long> recordsLocationList= new ArrayList<Long>();

public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
```

}

This is the change that is causing the error : 
`ois = new ObjectInputStream(new  BufferedInputStream(fis, 4096));` instead of `ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);`

The error is `java.io.StreamCorruptionException: invalid type code : 00`

EDIT :

I have now figured out the problem. While my fis was being positioned to a new position, my bis was not being skipped to that new position. Instead bis was trying to read from the old position only and hence the exception

Comment: what is the error you get with BufferedInputStream ? Technically , adding a BIS should never cause a problem( on account of its buffered style of reading because thats an implementation detail ).Also can you show how you wrap the OIS into a BIS which causes the error ?

Comment: I would have investigated what exactly was causing the error , but you may close the question if you feel right.

Comment: @Bha `ois = new ObjectInputStream(new  BufferedInputStream(fis, 4096));` instead of `ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);`

Comment: @Bha I have also added the error I am getting in the question. (I was mistakenly adding BIS to the wrong file and hence was getting it to run without error. However, the error is still there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indicative of a case where the bytes being read back from the stream ( and from the file ) are being interpreted as an object ( by the OIS ) but actually these bytes are something else ( not a byte representation of an actual object ). This may be because of the buffer size being specified explicitly ( combined with the fact that you are setting the position manually ).

I would suggest to try without specifying the buffer size explicitly.

`ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis))`

Comment: even without setting buffer size explicitly I get the same error. I understand it is being caused because I am setting position manually while bis is unaware that the underlying fc has been repositioned.

Comment: Now I am beginning to think of it , BIS does not buffer based on custom logic ( per object ) , it can only buffer based on raw bytes , while this use case requires it to buffer one or more ( but not a fraction there of ) object bytes. I am getting inclined to say that you would need to write a custom BIS for that purpose.

Comment: Well Java is pretty poor then. All I wanted to do was to be able to write objects in a file at various locations and being able to read, not one at a time, but by big blocks at a time which may contain one or more objects. I could have done this in c++ using simple read((sizeof)object * 20) and using my index to parse through the read bytes. In java I have wasted 3 days trying to figure this out and I am still nowhere. So much for the ease of use! Thankyou very much for y our effort

Comment: @AnkurVj , I would not agree with your view on Java being poor. If you notice , in your C++ code , you are writing code to tell it *how* you want it to buffer bytes ( by specifying sizeof and *20); Its the same in Java too - you would have to specify in code how the BIS should buffer - per object ( you would need to extend a class and override some methods to do that - but thats a different point ) On the converse , Java facilitates so much functionality by IO libraries - you would have a much steeper curve coding similar things in C++.

Comment: When i do a read or write using file input stream of a specified number of bytes, is each byte written using a separate system call or all bytes written using a single system call ?